# Spring MVC 3.0 Annotations - Conversation Forms - Beginner Questions

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

How do you do the following in Spring 3.0? (I found so many results, I'm not sure which is the right way)

What I want to know is how to do the following in the "best practice" standart Spring 3.0 Annotation way

- **Multiple page form** (How to use `@SessionAttributes`)
- **Multiple submit buttons** on a form (should I use `@RequestMapping(params={"btn1"}...)` ?)
- **Automatic binding** of form fields to beans (`@InitBinder`? must it use "Spring" forms?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Multiple page form -- have a look at Spring Web Flow
- Multiple submit buttons -- @RequestMapping(params={"btn1"}...)  should do the job
- Automatic binding -- better to use [Spring Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html#core-convert) with [Converters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) - (they are stateless in difference to Binders)

Comment: +1, but it's Spring Web Flow, not Spring Flow: http://www.springsource.org/webflow